# How to send parameters with jquery $.get()

Tags: ajax, jquery, get

I'm trying to do a jquery GET and i want to send a parameter.

here's my function:

```
$(function() {
    var availableProductNames;
    $.get("manageproducts.do?option=1", function(data){
        availableProductNames = data.split(",");;
        alert(availableProductNames);
        $("#nameInput").autocomplete({
            source: availableProductNames
        });
    });
});
```

This doesn't seem to work; i get a null in my servlet when i use `request.getParameter("option")`;

If i type the link into the browser http://www.myite.com/manageproducts.do?option=1 it works perfectly.

I also tried:

```
$.get(
    "manageproducts.do?",
    {option: "1"},
    function(data){}
```

which doesn't work either.

Can you please help me?

EDIT:

also tried

```
       $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "manageproducts.do",
     data: "option=1",
     success: function(msg){
        availableProductNames = msg.split(",");
        alert(availableProductNames);
        $("#nameInput").autocomplete({
        source: availableProductNames
    });   
     }
      });
```

Still getting the same result.

Comment: you were right i had a typo. it works with $.get("manageproducts.do", {option: "1"}, function(data){

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you say that it works with accessing directly `manageproducts.do?option=1` in the browser then it should work with:

```
$.get('manageproducts.do', { option: '1' }, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

as it would send the same GET request.

Comment: I was trying to pass an object into .get(), with the info as properties of that object. But as this answer shows, don't pass an object.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'manageproducts.do',
    data: 'option=1',
    success: function(data) {

        availableProductNames = data.split(",");

        alert(availableProductNames);

    }
});
```

Also You have a few errors in your sample code, not sure if that was causing the error or it was just a typo upon entering the question.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working : -

```
$.get('api.php', 'client=mikescafe', function(data) {
...
});
```

It sends via get the string ?client=mikescafe
then collect this variable in api.php, and use it in your mysql statement.

Comment: I have a function that returns the parameters for my `$.get`. Removing the curly brackets solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
$.get({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'api.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    // query parameters go under "data" as an Object
    data: {
        client: 'mikescafe'
    }
});
```

will make a `REST/AJAX call - > GET http://localhost:3000/api.php?client=mikescafe`

Good Luck.