# Can't find the right way to get parameter value from the HttpRequest:

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets

Can't find the right way to get parameter value from the HttpRequest:

this is my JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currBoard;
var currCell;
$(".cell").click(function() {

    Cardboard = $ (this). attr ('name');
    currCell = $(this).attr('id');
    $.get('InGameServlet', function(responseText) {
        $("#"+currCell).text(responseText);

        alert("cell num:" + currCell + " Board: " + currBoard);
    });
});
```

});

This is my Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "InGameServlet", urlPatterns = {"/InGameServlet"})
public class InGameServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    printSign(request.getParameter("currBoard"), request.getParameter("currCell"),     response);
}
```

In debug mode i see that the values i get from the request are NULL!

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `getAttribute()` instead of `getParameter()`.

Request parameters are stored as request parameters in the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Use

```
String value = request.getParameter("your parameter key");
```

This obviously depends on if your request actually contains request parameters. [Here's how you do that with jQuery's `get()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544160/how-to-send-parameters-with-jquery-get)

Comment: ohh sorry, it was one of the tests i did... they both return null.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing values from your ajax request

```
$(".cell").click(function() {

    Cardboard = $ (this). attr ('name');
    currCell = $(this).attr('id');
    $.get('InGameServlet?currBoard="+Cardboard+"currCell="+currCell', function(responseText) {  //passing data as quesry param.
        $("#"+currCell).text(responseText);

        alert("cell num:" + currCell + " Board: " + currBoard);
    });
});
```

Then in servlet get request parameters as

```
request.getParameter("currBoard");
```

So it becomes,

```
printSign(request.getParameter("currBoard"),request.getParameter("currCell"),response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be passing any parameter in your `$.get` ajax call.
In addition parameters are obtained by the `getParameter()` method not `getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to send the parameters with the request:

```
var data = {
    currBoard: $(this).attr('name'),
    currCell: $(this).attr('id')
};
$.get('InGameServlet', data, function (responseText) {
    $("#" + currCell).text(responseText);

    alert("cell num:" + currCell + " Board: " + currBoard);
});
```

Then retrieve them with `request.getParameter()` instead of `getAttribute()`