# Why does making a python Requests request work and Jquery ajax Get does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to make a ajax call with Jquery to retrieve json data from a website.  I can not get it to work in Jquery but I was able to make it work using the python Requests Library.  How can I get the ajax data using jquery?

This code works and gets me the data I want (However, I want it client side not server side)

```
import requests
request = requests.get('http://volaris.com/locations/json/autocomplete/?term=tij&where=&loc=&lang=en')
```

This code does not.  This is the code I would like to work.  As of now, it only hits the fail function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://volaris.com/locations/json/autocomplete/?term=tij&where=&loc=&lang=en',
    type: 'GET',
    daType: 'json',
    cache: true,
    error: function() {
        alert( "ajax error" );
    },
    success: function(json) {
        alert( "ajax success");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are looking something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544160/how-to-send-parameters-with-jquery-get

Comment: @Pavlo Doesn't look like it. The OP is making a cross-domain request; that seems to be the problem

Comment: I corrected some typos in my question. Nothing big. XDR seems to be the problem from what I have read but I don't know enough about it.  Wouldn't the python request library be an XDR request also and have the same problem?

Comment: python is not bound by the Same Origin Policy that JS is...

Comment: For a work around, I just used my server as proxy for the ajax call.

Comment: Similar question: [CORS error with Javascript but not with Python/PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134558/cors-error-with-javascript-but-not-with-python-php)